# Как изменить скролл в блоке?

Tags: html, css

для примера заменил в блоке сам позунок через псевдокласс, но ничего не поменялось:

```
.filter__checkbox-list {
    height: 105px;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;

    &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background: red;
    }

}
```

нужно было сделать так, но будут ли работать данные css свойства для блока?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: так? https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/15v7psza/

Comment: ага. почему-то работает именно если указывать саму ширину скролла, видимо это обязательно) как ответ опубликуйте ваш комментарий))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо добавить еще ширину скролбара

```
&::-webkit-scrollbar
```

Пример

```css
.filter__checkbox-list {
  height: 105px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.filter__checkbox-list label {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
}


/* Width */
.filter__checkbox-list::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 6px;
}


/* Thumb */
.filter__checkbox-list::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="filter__checkbox-list">
  <label><input type="checkbox"> List 1 </label>
  <label><input type="checkbox"> List 2 </label>
  <label><input type="checkbox"> List 3 </label>
  <label><input type="checkbox"> List 4 </label>
  <label><input type="checkbox"> List 5 </label>
  <label><input type="checkbox"> List 6 </label>
  <label><input type="checkbox"> List 7 </label>
  <label><input type="checkbox"> List 8 </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Без определения стилей для `::-webkit-scrollbar` работать не будет.

Попробуйте так:

```
.filter__checkbox-list {
    height: 105px;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.filter__checkbox-list::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    background-color: #ddd;
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: 7px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.filter__checkbox-list::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    background-color: #1955A8;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
```

Comment: &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb (используется препроцессор) = .filter__checkbox-list::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb - эти стили эквивалентны.

Comment: Знаю, но под рукой не было Less/Sass. Если нужно, исправлю под препроцессор.